# Getting CPU Temperature through Windows 8 Not Supported

Tags: c#, windows-8, wmi

So I've been trying to get the temperature of my CPU using WMI for some time now. Of the two machines I've tested on, the one with an intel processor and Windows 7 runs just fine, where the one with an AMD processor and Windows 8.1 fails. I'm using a simple snippet that I found on another question, but the question was old and there was no discussion of Windows 8/8.1. Here is the snippet:

```
public class Temperature
{
    public double CurrentValue { get; set; }
    public string InstanceName { get; set; }
    public static List<Temperature> Temperatures
    {
        get
        {
            List<Temperature> result = new List<Temperature>();
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature");
            foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Double temp = Convert.ToDouble(obj["CurrentTemperature"].ToString());
                temp = (temp - 2732) / 10.0;
                result.Add(new Temperature { CurrentValue = temp, InstanceName = obj["InstanceName"].ToString() });
            }
            return result;

        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I call `searcher.Get()` though, it causes a ManagementException with the message "Not Supported."

I know that I have all the necessary hardware requirements, as other tools (Core temp and Speccy) will return the temperature just fine.

In addition to this, I've also started researching `Win32_TemperatureProbe` but that hasn't panned out. If anyone knows of good reference material for that, I would greatly appreciate it if you would share.

Edit: I'm trying this on Windows 8.1 x64 with .NET 3.5. The processor is an AMD FX8350 and it's hooked up to a Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 Motherboard.

Comment: Can you add more details about the machine on which you are testing? (type, windows detailed version, .net framework version)

Comment: What do you mean by type? I built it myself if that's what you mean, but I'll add more detail to the post.

Comment: If it was a market machine, the reference, but you just said it's a custom one. It seems that the property you are requesting are not always available, depending on the platform/hardware (that may be the reason of your `Not supported` exception).

You can try with another tool for example, which is using another method to get the temperature (that may be the reason why other tools also work): http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?767189-RESOLVED-Cpu-Temperature

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I figured that if `Win32_TemperatureProbe` didn't pan out either I would end up looking into Open Hardware Monitor.

Comment: You can try to check Win32_TemperatureProbe with the following PowerShell:
$computer = "LocalHost" 
$namespace = "root\CIMV2" 
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_TemperatureProbe -computername $computer -namespace $namespace